# vis.js removing whole graph when deleting single node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, vis.js

I'm trying to delete a node from a vis.js graph. When the function is applied, instead of the node and its outgoing edges being deleted the entire graph gets erased. I want the changes to be kept intact when the page gets refreshed. The calls related to this are `deleteNode` (in index.html) and `app.delete` (in index.js).

index.html:

```
var deleteNode = function(data, callback){
  $.ajax({
    method: "delete",
    url: "/api/node",
    data: {node: data.nodes[0] },
    success: function(result){
      callback(result);
    }
  })
};
```

index.js:

```
app.delete("/api/node", function(req, res){
  var deleteNode = req.body.node;
  var deleteResult = {
    nodes:[],
    edges: []
  };

  var updatedNodes = _.filter(data.nodes, function(node){
    var keep = (node.id !== deleteNode);
    if(!keep){
      deleteResult.nodes.push(node);
    }
    return keep;
  });

  var updatedEdges = _.filter(data.edges, function(edge){
    var keep = (edge.from !== deleteNode) || (edge.to !== deleteNode);
    if(!keep){
      deleteResult.edges.push(node);
    }
    return keep;
  });

  data.nodes = updatedNodes;
  data.edges = updatedEdges;

  res.send(deleteResult).end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your logic is correct? That is the first thing I would check here. In particular, I see that your 'delete' method seems to be returning the 'deleteResult' variable, which is going to have probably all the nodes that you deleted as a consequence of the API call. Perhaps you wanted to return the 'data' variable instead?